# Powershell script to open multiple .SQL files and do a string replace of a particular word

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get a powershell script to recurse through all of the files in a single location and do a string replace on a particular word.

This is what I have so far but i can't get it to work.

```
$configFiles=get-childitem C:\DataFolder\Folder1\*.SQL -rec
foreach ($file in $configFiles)
{
(Get-Content $file.PSPath) | 
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "BCBS_MN", "XXXX_DB_NAME_XXXX"} | 
Set-Content $file.PSPath
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thankn - Brian

Comment: Not sure what you mean,  I am slow when it comes to powershell.
Would what you suggest replace my entire section? if not where are you adding it?

Comment: What exactly isn't working?  You said "I can't get it to work" but that could mean anything.  Are all of the files you want in $configFiles?  Is the replace working at all?  Or for some files but not others? Are any errors printing that you can share?

Comment: When I attempt to step through the code I get to the following line:
    Get-Content $file.PSPath)  | 
and it errors out.

Comment: + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand


This is the error, Sorry I keep hitting enter instead of Shift+Enter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Data Folder\Folder1\*.SQL" -recurse | ForEach {
    (Get-Content $_.PSPath) -replace "BCBS_MN", "XXXX_DB_NAME_XXXX" | Set-Content $_.PSPath
}
```

Comment: I think i am getting an error here because the pathname has spaces in it.  is there a way in PS to Qualify a path?

Comment: Nice! It works!  Thanks for the help.  I will be keeping this in my PS tool folder for future reference.